# Android webview in Unity3d (C#)

Tags: android, webview, unity-game-engine

I am doing a game application using unity3d for Android. In that I popup one alert box, which will show some message like "Do you want to proceed click 'OK' or 'Cancel'". If the user clicks "ok" I want to forword them to some webpage like 'https://stackoverflow.com/' .

This is possible in android using "Webview" android code. Now my question is How can I use this webview in Unity3d(C# code).

I have searched over the net and got the following links:

https://github.com/gree/unity-webview

https://github.com/kimsama/unity3d-webview-csharp

I have downloaded these codes. But I couldn't execute these samples. If anyone used these samples, Please give me the steps to execute these? or can anybody give other samples will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 4):

I made a similar WebView plugin based on gree's webview, in which I modified some code to let it run in Mac Editor (and of course you can use it in both iOS and Android). There is also a valid demo for you in the repo. You can try it.

[UniWebView - a Unity3D webview plugin for iOS, Android and Mac](https://github.com/onevcat/UniWebView)

Comment: i am curious, did you used any solutions ? I know it's an old question, i am looking for a response now too . thank you.

Comment: @user1140656 what do you mean by saying " did you used any solutions "?

Comment: if the above suggested solution worked for you? The UniWebView - a Unity3D webview plugin for iOS, Android and Mac

Comment: :) I wrote these code, of course it solved my problems.

Comment: Try to put the real code instead of links, otherwise, imho, the stack post it has no value.

Answer (score 1):

My team had this same case, except we wanted something that works with both 2D and 3D. We looked at different options and ended up using the [Unity 3D WebView plugin](https://developer.vuplex.com/webview/overview). Here's what our code looks like:

```
void ShowWebView(Vector3 position) {

    var webPrefab = WebViewPrefab.Instantiate(0.5f, 0.5f); // specify the size
    webPrefab.transform.parent = this.transform;
    webPrefab.transform.position = position;
    webPrefab.transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform);
    webPrefab.Initialized += (sender, e) => webPrefab.WebView.LoadUrl("https://example.com");
}
```